# SendGrid spec differences between versions of Event Notification Webhook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I have an existing rails3 application with **SendGrid Service** integration based on SMTP relay, and  subscribed to **Event Notification Webhooks**.

I've got reminder email from Service, informing about impending change to SendGrid's service, and I need make some changes to match new version of Event Notification Webhooks v3.

Email I got contains instructions about How To Upgrade:

- Review the documentation to understand how to consume this new version's events.
- **Implement changes on your side to handle the new in-formatting of event data.**
- Make changes on SendGrid's configuration page

I wounder, what changes now need I implement on my site? I read manual for v3, but there no information about specifications differences between old and new versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously, the SendGrid event webhook sent improper batched JSON, with documents seperated by line breaks:

```
{ "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com", "timestamp": 1337197600, "smtp-id": "<4FB4041F.6080505@sendgrid.com>", "event": "processed" }
{ "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com", "timestamp": 1337966815, "category": "newuser", "event": "click", "url": "http://sendgrid.com" }
{ "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com", "timestamp": 1337969592, "smtp-id": "<20120525181309.C1A9B40405B3@Example-Mac.local>", "event": "processed" }
```

Today, with `v3` it sends proper JSON as such:

```
[
  {
    "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com",
    "timestamp": 1337197600,
    "smtp-id": "<4FB4041F.6080505@sendgrid.com>",
    "event": "processed"
  },
  {
    "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com",
    "timestamp": 1337966815,
    "category": "newuser",
    "event": "click",
    "url": "http://sendgrid.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "john.doe@sendgrid.com",
    "timestamp": 1337969592,
    "smtp-id": "<20120525181309.C1A9B40405B3@Example-Mac.local>",
    "event": "processed"
  }
]
```

If you'd previously been dealing with non-batched events you'll need to adjust your code so that it interprets an array, rather than just a single document, and then loops through said array. Put into code:

```
# This
consume_data(params)

# Becomes this
params.each { |doc|
  consume_data(doc)
}
```